# Unexpected behaviour converting a string to a const char*

Tags: c++, string

I need to convert a `std::string` to a `const char*`.

To do so, I used the `c_str()` method on the string, as in the following code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    string testStr;
    cin >> testStr;

    const char* testStrConst = testStr.c_str();

    cout << testStrConst << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If I type `"Hey hello"` in the terminal, when this code is running, the output is only `"Hey"`.

Why is the second word ignored?

Comment: The `operator>>()` reads word wise (skips whitespaces). Use `getline()` instead.

Comment: You might want to print out testStr before jumping to conclusions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because it was never a part of the `std::string` in the first place.

The `>>` operator reads only a single, whitespace delimited word.

Use `std::getline()` instead of `>>` to read the entire line of text entered on standard input.

```
string testStr;
getline(cin, testStr);
```